# Checking the result of solve_ivp with solve_bvp - solve_bvp problems

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations, boundary

I am hoping to use `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` to solve a 2nd order differential equation: I am checking my process with a previous equation, so I am confident in moving onto more complex equations.

We begin with the differential equation system:

```
f''(x) + f(x) - f(x)^3 = 0
```

subject to the boundary conditions

```
f(x=0) = 0        f(x->infty) = gammaA
```

where `gammaA` is some constant between 0 and 1. I am finding numerical solutions for this, and comparing to a known analytic form (at least, for gammaA =1, a tanh function). For any given `gammaA`, we can integrate this equation once to and utilise the BC at infinity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

gammaA = 0.9
xstart = 0.0
xend = 10
steps = 0.1
x = np.arange(xstart,xend,steps)

def dpsidx3(x,psi, gammaA):
    eq = ( gammaA**2 *(1 - (1/2)*gammaA**2) - psi**2 *(1 - (1/2)*psi**2) )**0.5
    return eq

psi0 = 0
x0 = xstart
x1 = xend

sol = solve_ivp(dpsidx3, [x0, x1], y0 = [psi0], args = (gammaA,), dense_output=True, rtol = 1e-9)

plotsol = sol.sol(x)
plt.plot(x, plotsol.T,marker = "", linestyle="--",label = r"Numerical solution - $solve\_ivp$")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('psi')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

If `gammaA` is not 1, then there are some runtime warnings but the shape is exactly as expected.
However, the ODE in the `solve_ivp` code has been manipulated into a form which is a 1st order ODE; for further work (with more complex and variable coefficients in the ODE), this will not be possible. Hence, I am trying to solve the boundary value problem using `solve_bvp`.
I am trying to solve now the same ODE, but I am not getting the same result as from this solution; the documentation is unclear on how to effectively use `solve_bvp` to me! Here is my attempt so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

gammaA = 0.9
xstart = 0.0
xend = 10
steps = 0.1

def fun(x,u):
    du1 = u[1] #u[1] = u2, u[0] = u1
    du2 = u[0]**3 - u[0]
    return np.vstack( (du1, du2) ) 

def bc(ua, ub):
    return np.array( [ua[0], ub[0]-gammaA])

x = np.linspace(xstart, xend, 10)
print(x.size)
y_a = np.zeros((2, x.size))
y_a[0] = np.linspace(0, gammaA, 10)
y_a[0] = gammaA

res_a = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_a, max_nodes=100000, tol=1e-9)
print(res_a)

x_plot = np.linspace(0, xend, 100)
y_plot_a = res_a.sol(x_plot)[0]

fig2,ax2= plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(x_plot, y_plot_a, label=r'BVP solve')
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_xlabel("x")
ax2.set_ylabel("psi")
```

I have tried to write the 2nd order ODE as a system of 1st order ODEs and set the correct boundary conditions at the end of the system (rather than at infinity). I expected a similar tanh-function (where I could say that after the end of the system, my solution is simply `gammaA`, as expected by the asymptote), but it is clear that I am not getting this for any value of `gammaA`. Any advice gratefully appreciated; how can I reproduce the result of `solve_ivp` in `solve_bvp`?

EDIT: extra thoughts.
Can I add an additional constraint to my problem to ensure that the solution has a stationary point at the edge/is a monotonically increasing solution? The plots look okay for `gammaA =1`, but do not show the correct behaviour for any other values as in `solve_ivp`.

EDIT2: comparative figures, showing poor agreement with gammaA, e.g. 0.8 but good agreement for gammaA = 1.
[image: gamma0.8]
[image: gamma1]

Answer (score 0):

You are making unfounded assumption on the mathematical nature of this equation. There is an energy functional

```
E = u'^2 + u^2 - 0.5*u^4 - 0.5 = u'^2 - 0.5*(u^2-1)^2
```

The solution that you first computed is at energy level 0.

For any smaller, negative energy level, roughly inside the unit circle, you get periodic oscillating solutions, these have no limit at infinity.
For larger, positive energy levels the solutions are unbounded, will rapidly grow larger, possibly diverge in finite time. Also here the limit at infinity either does not exist, as there is no solution connecting the initial point to large times, or the limit is infinity itself.

Forcing boundary conditions against this nature might work, but will not give a stable solution.